# Palm Pre Dashboard notification

Tags: webos, palm-pre, mojo-sdk

How can I get Dashboard notification in my Palm-Pre application?

Comment: kudos for asking such a clear, detailed question. I'm sure it will get may useful answers....or NOT...

Answer (score 4):

A dashboard notification is just another view in the application.  Dashboard panels are covered in the Mojo SDK documentation at http://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1632.

Answer (score 0):

Call this.notify() and declare notify() as following

```
YourAssistant.prototype.notify = function(custom,event) {
    console.log("################# NOTIFY ############")
    var target = custom;
    var appController = Mojo.Controller.getAppController();
    this.controller.commitChanges();
    var bannerParams = {
        soundClass: '', 
        soundFile: '', 
        icon: '',
        messageText: 'hahaha hahaha'
    }
    appController.showBanner(bannerParams, {banner: this.message});
}
```